# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined -underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am a beginner in underscore.js and jquery , and when I create a simple template as given below :

```
<html>
<body>

    <script src="E:/its me/softies/blackhole.com/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type ="text/javascript" id="tem">
        var head = "hii";
        //var head2 = "hello";
        var templ = _.template($('#temp').html()) ;
        $('#tagent').append(templ,{head:head});        
    </script>

      <script type="text/template" id="temp">
    <h1><%=head></h1>
    <h2><%=head2></h2>
    </script>

    <div class="tangent"></div>
</body>
```

it shows a error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`
 I use the brackets editor. I would be so thankful if someone could tell me 
1)what kind of error is this??
2)where I have gone wrong?? . thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is executed before your template is available, you need to ether execute it on [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback) or move your script block below your template definition.

Comment: now it throws this error : Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-js: "file:///E:/its%20me/softies/blackhole.com/underscore.js"   on line 4 (line where I have put my underscore lib function from github)

Comment: This should be a warning, not an error right? Its caused by you serving from the filesystem instead of a proper webserver. Try using something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for development. Otherwise please open a new question.